# Accessibility scope of Java access modifiers

Tags: java, access-modifiers

Java has private, protected, and public access modifiers. Can you explain the accessibility scope of these modifiers.

How can I access a protected member within a different package?

Comment: FInd here [http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/accesscontrol.html](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/accesscontrol.html)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15939002/protected-access-modifier-in-java

Comment: The table in the official tutorial (which is copied in the accepted answer) isn't super pedagogical imo. Have a look at [this table](http://stackoverflow.com/a/33627846/276052) for a slightly better visualization.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

For better understanding you need to see this

```
Access Modifiers

                   Same Class      Same Package            Subclass     Other packages
public               Y                Y                      Y                   Y
protected            Y                Y                      Y                   N
no access modifier   Y                Y                      N                   N
private              Y                N                      N                   N
```

Here the important difference is between `Default` and `protected`.
 **Default:** Never accessible outside the package
**Protected:** Only accessible outside the package, if and only if the class is a subclass.
**Edit:** As your question's answer is also the same that *`You can access the protected member by make your class a sub class of the class , in which protected member is defined`*