# Java: protected methods not accessed in different class of different package when I used extends keyword to achieve multiple inheritance

Tags: java

I Have following two classes:
Test.java

```
package com.test.app;

public class Test {

    public int a=10;
    protected void testFunc() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        System.out.println("Test class--> testFunc");
    }
}
```

Another One is
Main.java
package com.test.main;

```
import com.test.app.Test;


public class Main extends Test {


    public static void main(String[] argv) {

        System.out.println("Main Method");

        Main main =new Main();
        main.testFunc(); // No Error


        Test test = new Test();
        test.testFunc(); // Error

    }

}
```

The method test.testFunc() from the type Test is not visible

Comment: what is the question?

Comment: Yes, that's how packages work.

Comment: That's a feature... not a bug...

Comment: I'm unable to access protected method in main method

Comment: I think http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16074621/accessebility-scope-of-java-access-modifiers link will help you more.

Answer (score 1):

The `Test#testFunc()` method is only accessible for sub-classes (like `Main`) and for classes in the same package (`com.test.app`).

This is why the statement

```
main.testFunc();
```

compiles fine (because `Main` is a sub-class of `Test` and it's allowed to call `testFunc()`).

---

This statement, however

```
test.testFunc();
```

doesn't compile, because the package where the `Main` class is located is not `com.test.app`, but `com.test.main`.

More info:

- [Difference between `public`, `default`, `protected`, and `private`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/215497/difference-among-public-default-protected-and-private)

Comment: [this, especially the top comment on the accepted answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/215505/2988942) is a nice reference/proof addition to your answer :)

Comment: Yes I agree with your answer but here my question is I'm extending from super class so in this case protected methods should be available in different package ??

Comment: So in above Main class can get feature of Test class including protected method right!??  But testFunc() can not visible in Main class when I used object of Test class I.e test.testFunc()