# Not able to see clone() method in suggestion list in java?

Tags: java, clone, cloneable

When I opened `Object class` source code I can see the `clone()` method in it.

When I try to see `clone()` method in the method list doesn't show up 
(If I create `object` of `MyClass` as `myClass` and apply `. dot operator` it gives me suggestion of all available methods in eclipse IDE but it doesn't show `clone()` method in that list!!)

`MyClass myClass = new MyClass();
myClass. // here I expect to see clone() as well but not`

why it happens ????

Comment: By default, `clone` is `protected`.  You have to purposefully override it and change it's access level to `public`

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why is the clone() method protected in java.lang.Object?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1138769/why-is-the-clone-method-protected-in-java-lang-object)

Comment: In other Custom classes I can see protected methods..... but Java core classes we cant see is it ???

Comment: @JordiCastilla Not exactly.

Comment: just curious about why its not visible only for Java core classes .... Custom classes we can see though !! ... what is the thinking behind doing it

Comment: @sᴜʀᴇsʜᴀᴛᴛᴀ Yes (it's not package private), as I said, you can override the method and even make it `public`

Comment: @MadProgrammer Got that.

Answer (score 1):

If you consider [official  Oracle Java documentation for Object class](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html) you can find that the `clone()` method  is protected, due to polymorphism this method will be able only in the same package or in the child class, but not the outside it.

So, the method would be able **only** in package `java.lang` and **only** in all children of this class, **but not** in the packages where children has been declared. Try to read [this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15939002/protected-access-modifier-in-java) to rise you understanding about java access modifiers

**But there is one thick here**: you can make override of this method like this

```
    @Override
    protected Object clone() throws CloneNotSupportedException {
        return super.clone();
    }
```

and after that you be able to use method `clone` in the same package where declared your class `MyClass`, but be prepared to get `CloneNotSupportedException`

Also you be able to use your own implementation. Just implement `Clonable` interface and provide your own `clone` method.

Also, if you planing that the clonned object must be equals you also should override `equals` method too.

Good Luck!

Comment: Protected can be seen outside of the package as well to the Child  ...... and Object is Parent class for every single user created class ... so  was thinking why its happening why they dont show clone method as well.

Comment: try to read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15939002/protected-access-modifier-in-java)

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps the creator of the object you are trying to clone made the clone method private. Also you probably shouldn't rely on Eclipse autocomplete especially if you're just starting out with Java.

Comment: this is best I think ..... better not to break head in it .. its choice of eclipse creators not to show protected methods as suggestions :)

Answer (score 0):

The java.lang.Cloneable interface must be implemented by the class

MyClass implements Cloneable.